# Vector computation does not match output

Tags: java, arrays

Im constructing a Vector class, in which one of the methods includes setting a vector sequence in which the user specifies the starting number and the step and the vector prints the sequence. When i run the program however, it sets the values default to 0 and does not implement the step.

```
public static Vector sequence(int length, long start, long step) {

    /*
        TODO

        length 1, start 1, step 1  => [1]
        length 2, start 2, step 2  => [2 4]
        length 3, start 3, step 3  => [3 6 9]
        length 4, start 4, step 4  => [4 8 12 16]
        length 5, start 5, step -1 => [5 4 3 2 1]
    */

    Vector vector = new Vector(length);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        start += start + step;
    }

    return new Vector(length);
}
```

Please help me with this code.

Comment: Why not set the value of elements in the vector? Reference: [Vector (Java Platform SE 8 )](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html)

Comment: @Shahrokh Aryana Your method only performs operations on the parameters passed into the method and never uses them to modify the vector in any way.  Plus, you create a new vector in the return statement, so any changes prior to that would get ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Vector vector = new Vector(length);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        vector.add(start += start + step);
    }

    return vector;
```

I didn't change the formula of your program since you hopefully know what you are doing. Answer to your question lies in adding elements to `vector` and return that.

Answer (score 1):

- Add the values calculated to the elements of the vector. Setting capacity doesn't mean to make elements, so `set` won't work.
- The formula is wrong.
- You have to return the vector to which values are set, not newly created vector.

corrected code:

```
public static Vector sequence(int length, long start, long step) {

    Vector vector = new Vector(length);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        vector.add(start + step * i);
    }

    return vector;
}
```

Comment: When i run the program it says that the .set function cannot be found, even though i have imported the package

Comment: @ShahrokhAryana This program [works](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/sBuIWGF5oRnnsEuF). Please don't criticize my old code, which I myself said is not working.